# How do you style svg tags using css?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to use an inline style tag to style my 45 polygons and 5 rectangles. 
for some reason the first tag that i try to style does not pick up the styling. If I add a third shape at the top then the two underneath it get styled, if I removed the third shape at the top then the second one under it will not be styled. Has this happened to anyone before?

```
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
      <!--this rectangle will not be styled -->
      rect{
        fill:none;
        stroke:black;
        stroke-width:.5;
      }
      polygon{
        fill:none;
        stroke:black;
        stroke-width:.5;
      }



]]></style>
```

Now using the code below, the rectangle gets styled. (with the second polygon tag at the top)

```
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

  polygon{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:.5;
  }
  rect{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:.5;
  }
  polygon{
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:.5;
  }
]]></style>
 <svg width="400" height="800" viewBox="0 0 400 800" id="svg-doc">
<rect id="central-park" class="shape" x="154" y="370"width="53" height="127" />
          <rect id="shape-z10024" class="shape" x="68" y="415" width="85" height="40" />
          <rect id="shape-z10023" class="shape" x="68" y="457" width="85" height="40"  />
          <polygon id="shape-z10034" class="shape" points="189,156 137,122 106,121 101,129 99,155 79,155 78,105 94,79 121,67 128,82 163,61 177,62 191,80" />
          <a xlink:href="http://google.com/">
            <polygon id="shape-z10040" class="shape" points="188,167 186,155 137,122 108,122 102,126 100,153 77,156 77,166" />
          </a>
          <polygon id="shape-z10033" class="shape" points="189,166 187,197 187,203 81,203 77,194 78,166" /> 
          <polygon id="shape-z10032" class="shape" points="189,205 160,234 155,248 84,247 80,204" />
          <polygon id="shape-z10030" class="shape" points="268,311 196,315 197,299 157,298 157,273 234,273" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Comment: Why do you have an XML comment in `<style>` tags? Is it there in your actual stylesheet? Also, try wrapping your CDATA delimiters in CSS comments (not XML comments). Also, need to see your SVG markup.

Comment: @BoltClock I was just following the manual online, not really sure why it was needed but i saw that thats what they used to do an inline style sheet. I added my markup as well, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It appears your problem is simply the comments inside the `<style>` tag. Your code works with them removed … see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/thatmichael/tcaTP/

(I changed the fills to make it more obvious that the CSS is working.)